# "Si l'on apprenait que"... Purpose of direct object pronoun?

Tags: grammaire

In the following sentence, why is there a direct object pronoun "l'" after "si"? Is it only for the purpose of euphony (sounds better than "si on"), or is there a grammatical purpose I'm missing? It doesn't seem necessary because there is already the pronoun "on."

"Si l'on apprenait qu'il ne nous reste qu'une journée à vivre, ce qui nous paraît catastrophique deviendrait soudain très relatif."

Answer (score 1):

In this construction and others (Ainsi l'on, que l'on,…) "l" is considered to be an expletive ; here are a few essential facts to know about this expletive.

> [l´on ou on á l écrit - Question Orthographe Voltaire](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/l-on-ou-on-a-l-ecrit/)
>
> *On* peut être remplacé par *l’on* pour des raisons d’euphonie en particulier après ***et, ou, où, que, à qui, quoi, si** :
> ♦ il vint et l’on put s’expliquer.
> ♦ Si l’on nous entendait (Acad.).
> ♦ À l’heure oû l’on n’entend plus rien.
> ♦ Si l’on vous voit. Ce que l’on conçoit bien s’énonce clairement (Boileau).
> On évitera les allitérations dans le genre : Et l’on lui lava la tête. Si l’on le lui disait.
> Certains auteurs emploient néanmoins *l’on* sans que l’euphonie soit en cause :
> ♦  Par instants, l’on n’y comprend plus rien du tout (Gide).
> *l’on* en tête de phrase, autrefois très usité, ne s’emploie plus que rarement.:
> ♦ L’on ne vient à bout des sauvages que par une sauvagerie perfectionnée (A. France).

The following article provides other  details : [Antidote, *On* et *l'on*](https://www.antidote.info/fr/blogue/enquetes/et-lon).

Comment: I would probably avoid "expletive* because I have the impression its usual meaning is "swear word".

Comment: @jlliagre True, the  meaning is much more often "swear word", but in my grammar there is no other term  than "expletive it" to show the empty semantic purpose of the word "it" in for example, "it's two o'clock"; the other term, "prop *it*", does not confer this idea. Moreover, "filler word" wouldn't do as filler can always be done away with. I think there is no better choice, and in fact this grammatical acceptation of the term is the first one treated in the Wikipedia ([expletive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive)).